# Integrating special function and plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, integrate, bessel-functions

I am trying to plot an integration of a special (eg. Bessel) function and my minimal code is the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as sp
from scipy.special import jn


#x = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)
U = np.linspace(0,10,1000)



#Delta = U**2
#Delta = U-4+8*integrate.quad(lambda x: sp.jv(1,x)/(x*(1.0+np.exp(U*x*0.5))), 0, 100)
Delta = U-4+8*integrate.quad(lambda x: jn(1,x)/(x*(1.0+np.exp(U*x*0.5))), 0.1, 1000)

plt.plot(U,Delta)

plt.xlabel('U')
plt.ylabel('$\Delta$')
plt.show()
```

However, this gives me several an error messages saying `quadpack.error: Supplied function does not return a valid float` whereas the function gets easily plotted in *Mathematica*. Do Python's Bessel's functions have limitations?

I have used this [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) for my plotting.

Comment: Your integral over [0,4.5] is a single number, not an array.  What are you trying to plot?

Comment: @StephenTerry sorry posted a wrong question, I have edited the post.

Comment: *"I am trying to **plot an integration** of a special (eg. Bessel) function"*. I do not know what this is... Please explain in more details what exactly are you trying to plot.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to provide an answer that solves the problem before understanding what exactly you are trying to do. However, let me list a number of issues and provide an example that may not achieve what you are trying to do but at least it will provide a path forward.

1. Because your lambda function multiplies `x` by an array `U`, it returns an array instead of a number. A function that needs to be integrated should return a single number. You could fix this, for example, by replacing `U` by `u`:

   ```
   f = lambda x, u: jn(1,x)/(x*(1.0+np.exp(u*x*0.5)))
   ```
2. Make `Delta` a function of `u` AND make `quad` pass additional argument `u` to `f` (defined in the previous point) AND extract only the value of the integral from the returned tuple from `quad` (`quad` returns a tuple of several values: the integral, the error, etc.):

   ```
    Delta = lambda u: -4+8*integrate.quad(f, 0.1, 1000, args=(u,))[0]
   ```
3. Compute `Delta` for each `u`:

   ```
    deltas = np.array(map(Delta, U))
   ```
4. plot the data:

   ```
    plt.plot(U, deltas)
   ```